# DTMF Detection in Asterisk PBX

Tags: asterisk, pbx, elastix

I have an asterisk server as IP PBX. I have created an Auto-Attendant for my company and asking users to enter desired extensions when they call. The problem is that when the message is playing and user enters the digits on his/her phone, some of DTMF digits are not recognized. I have enabled console logging for debugging DTMF input.
I use PSTN lines.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What hardware are you using?

Comment: I Use Digium AEX410.

Comment: Are you writing your own dialplan? Or are you using one of the free platforms like FreePBX or Elastix? In my experience, issues like this happen with poorly written dialplans.

Comment: @Matt W:I write my own dialplan in Asterisk. What can make a problem in dialplan?

Comment: The thing about Dialplan applications is that they are blocking. The best way to read in multiple DTMF digits is with Read(). If you are reading in each individual digit, chances are the callers are pressing the keys while your dial plan is executing an application or subroutine. If you are using Read(), there's a chance you may need to add relaxdtmf=yes inside of your configuration.